# Missing var directory after Apache httpd installation

Tags: apache

I installed apache httpd on my linux vm and wanted to start it's service. BUt I'm getting error `(13)Permission denied. Error retrieving pid file run/httpd.pid` I realised that I do not have this file. Not even a var directory. Any solutions for this? Pardon me, this is my first time touching servers.

I installed the apache like this:

`gzip -d httpd-2.2.21.tar.gz`

`tar xvf httpd-2.2.21.tar`

`./configure --prefix=/home/Hend/Desktop/Server`

`make`

`make install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several alternatives for this:

### Install apache in user directory, run as non-root user

This is the way you started doing that. But then you'll have to:

- Add some customizations to the start script, or at least pass it enough environment variables to tell him where configuration / pidfile / etc. are
- Modify the whole apache configuration, since the default uses directories to which you don't have access. For example, you should put your `DocumentRoot` somewhere else thant `/var/www`
- Run the server on a non-standard port. Since unprivileged users cannot run services on ports lower than 1024, you must run apache on another port, such as `8000` instead of `80`. But this way, all your URLs will look like `http://example.com:8000` instead of `http://example.com`.

### Install apache from sources, into `/usr/local`

You can install apache in the default path for non-part-of-distro stuff, that is `/usr/local` instead of `/usr/`. That is, use `--prefix=/usr/local/` when running `configure`.
This way, things should be much simpler. In any case, you'll have to run the webserver from root, and configure it to change user only after socket is opened.

### Install apache from sources, into `/usr/`

You can also install apache in its default location, usint `--prefix=/usr/`. This way things should be much simpler, it should install init scripts in the usual location `/etc/init.d/apache2` or `/etc/init.d/httpd`, configuration in `/etc/apache2` etc.
Beware that doing this all the apache installed files will conflict with the ones of the version provided by your linux distribution!

### Install apache from your distribution package manager

A part from the case in which you want particular setups (for example with non-standard patches), particular non-packaged versions (not recommended, since usually versions packaged with distros are guaranteed to be stable, others are not).

Benefits of doing this:

- Avoid huge setup + configuration process to make it work
- Versions from your distro should be "guaranteed" to be stable and tested with all the other programs shipped with it. Not always the latest version is better.
- Each time a new release is updated (or more importantly, there is a security update), you can upgrade it semi-automatically by running a single upgrade command, without worrying about things going wrong during update.
- This way the whole installation is just matter of a couple commands.

For example, on debian:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

On fedora:

```
yum install httpd
```

etc.

Then, if the service is not already started by package manager, you can start it with

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Job done. Now just put stuff in `/var/www/` (or equivalent directory, depends on distro) and see it through you web server.

Comment: Hi. That was a very useful information. But I'm sticking with the first as for now. Currently, I'm running as root already and the /var directory problem is gone. But is still unable to bind address. I have stated the ServerName and ServerAddress already. And ensured that the port is unused. Do you know what may be the issue?

Comment: @Hend do you have another webserver installed?

Comment: @redShadow - I think you should list some disadvantages of using the distro version ;-P  - ie like they all put configs in different places

Comment: This is a new account just created so there's no other webservers in it. The current one is the only one. Was wondering what else do I need to add in my httpd.conf? I did a telnet to myself port 80 but was unable to do so but able to ping myself.

Comment: @Hend which kind of machine are you working on? What do you mean with "this is a new account"? If you are running a webserver *on the same machine* you won't be able to run another one on the same port. A part from if you have different NIC cards, with different IPs, and you put each server listening only on its own address..

Comment: @AdrianCornish I dont' see that as a disadvantage over installing from sources, since 1. Usually, default configuration from distros (like debian) has a good structure to easily add/remove pieces of configuration, such as vhosts; 2. I don't see the difference between having the configuration in a location or another, in each case you have to find out where it is; 3. You can always change the structure of the configuration, since it's all done with `Import`s in cfg files. For example, I restructured configuration in a debian-like fashion on Fedora machines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start apache as root

Have you read the docs in the source distribution?

ie INSTALL

```
less INSTALL

  For complete installation documentation, see [ht]docs/manual/install.html or
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html

     $ ./configure --prefix=PREFIX
     $ make
     $ make install
     $ PREFIX/bin/apachectl start
```

Comment: So my installation is alright? Or do I have to reinstall as root?

Comment: If you downloaded a source package - then you also need to most likely need to install as root. But apache must be started as root because it uses a privileged port below 1024 - web servers listen on port 80

Comment: I downloaded the stable release 2.2.21 from the site. But is it normal to have the missing /var directory?

Comment: What site? Never install stuff from random sites. /var exists on every linux distro I've ever used (and a lot of unix installs as well) - you as a run of the mill user do not have access to this.

Comment: Downloaded it from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi   So, my installation is alright, just that I would need to start as root? Or do I have to install everything again as root? And downloading as root means I could use su or have to login into root? Sorry for the long question. And for the editted answer, yes i ran that. But i ran into unable to bind to address. For that, I found out it was about root privileges.

Comment: 99% sure starting as root will solve your issue - the other possibility is that its expecting PREFIX/var to exist or that its expecting a ~/var/run directory. I always install apache as a system wide thing rather than under a user

Comment: why are you installing apache that way? why not just use your distro package manager to install it?

Comment: @redShadow I agree with the OP - distro's turned into dependency bloat ware - I want complete control over my LAMP system - and not drag in. If mysql/php/apache release a new version tomorrow I want to try it and not wait for someone to package it.

Comment: It seems that the /var directory has other files too. How should I download it as a system wide? Which way would work flawlessly? So running as root will solve the /var issue?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I hope you are not speaking of *production* servers.. You not only "wait for someone to package it", but also (usually, on distros like debian/centos) be sure that somebody tested it and the version you are going to use is stable enough. I agree sometimes you want to have full control over the compilation -- use gentoo then. Compiling software from sources inside binary distros is almost 99% of times a bad idea. Anyways, it doesn't look like OP have enough knowledges to make benefit on customizing compilation options, am I right?

Comment: @Hend, which exact error are you getting? In console and/or in the logs (if there's any). And, which command are you using to start your server? Never launched apache manually, but theres' an option to tell it where is the configuration, then from the configuration you can change the location of files to something else, like `/home/youruser/www`; by using options you can also specify different locations for pid file, etc.

Comment: @redShadow I'm using PREFIX/bin/apachectl start. And getting the error (13)Permission denied. Error retrieving pid file run/httpd.pid. As well as httpd -k start.

Comment: Ok, I used an answer to explain things better. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @redShadow - yeah I do - but since its my personal (very boring) sites I dont think I attract enough attention to get hacked anyways :-). Also I think there are arguments for use distro packaged stuff and to pick and mix building. Both create and mitigate security problems.